# React Router changes url but not the view , it needs to be refreshed to render the component

Tags: reactjs, routes, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a NavBar component with a button to Route the url changes correctly but the page need to be refreshed first to render the view , All other routes works well except for this 
My code:

NavBar:

```
import {
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  NavItem,Button,
  NavLink,
} from 'reactstrap';
import { LinkContainer } from "react-router-bootstrap";
import { BrowserRouter  } from 'react-router-dom';





export default class NavBar extends React.Component {

    this.state = {
      isOpen: false,
      searchText:"",
        };
  }
        async handleSearchInput(e){
        this.setState({searchText:e.target.value});
    }

      submitSearch = () => {

}

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
        <Navbar className='Nav' color="" dark  expand="md">


        <NavItem className="searchInput">
        <input
        form-control input-lg
         placeholder="Search for movies..."
         ref={input => this.search = input}
         onChange={this.handleSearchInput}/>
           </NavItem>


          <NavItem>
          <BrowserRouter>

          <LinkContainer  to={{
            pathname:'/search',
            search: `${this.state.searchText}`,
            state: { searchText: this.state.searchText }}}>

           <Button  color="danger" size="lg"  navbar-btn >Search
           </Button>
           </LinkContainer>
           </BrowserRouter>

              </NavItem>

            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
    );
  }
}
```

Routes:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route , Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../home';
import NowPlaying from '../Movies/NowPlaying';
import TopRated from '../Movies/TopRated';
import Popular from '../Movies/popular';
import Search from '../Search/searchMovies';
import Movie from '../Movies/Movie';

const Routes = () => (
<Router>
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
    <Route path="/now_playing" component={NowPlaying}/>
    <Route path="/top_rated" component={TopRated}/>
    <Route  path="/popular" component={Popular}/>
    <Route forceRefersh={true} path="/search" component={Search}/>
    <Route path="/movie/:id" component={Movie}/>
</Switch>
  </Router>

)
export default Routes;
```

The route after clicking the button changes but I need to click on refresh to render the component , How to solve this issue?

Comment: `<Route forceRefersh={true} path="/search" component={(Search)}/>`
Why the Search is in paranthesis, do it like: `component={Search}`

Comment: @Oner T I fixed it , still same problem